# string** array; Seg fault on array[row][col] = "string"; C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

For an assignment I have to create a string ** array and manipulate. The guidelines say you can create a string as follows and then assign it as follows.

Code:

```
string **diceArray;    

diceArray[0][0] = "t";
diceArray[0][1] = "e";
diceArray[0][2] = "l";
diceArray[0][3] = "l";
```

I also tried  the below code to allocate but this also fails

```
string ** diceArray;
diceArray = new string*[rows];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i<rows; i++){
   diceArray[rows] = new string[cols];
}
```

Comment: You forgot to allocate with `new`, but you should be using `std::vector` instead of raw arrays.

Comment: Your problem is that you're defining diceArray as a pointer to a string pointer.  But That only allocates enough space for the pointer to the pointer.  Then you try to dreference the pointer twice - but there's nothing actually stored at the value of the pointer, so you're getting a segfault.

Comment: Posted my attempts at allocation above but this does not work either.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have referenc to adress to the memory (memory pointer) and you need to reserve space for that data.
If you will have always same size string buffer you can create your variable

```
string diceArray[1][4];
```

or if you will need dynamic size of the string with dynamic numbers of words you can use something like this.

```
string **str = new string*[x];
for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
str[i] = new string[y];
```

Comment: Not sure what I did in my original attempt at this format to make this fail but it seems to work now without seg fault. THANKS! much appreciated